# codeigniter .htaccess in amazon ec2 removal of index.php not working

Tags: php, codeigniter, amazon-ec2

codeigniter `.htaccess` in amazon ec2 removal of index.php not working

code

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase http://ec2-xx-xxx-xx-xx.us-west-2.compute.amazonaws.com/
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule .* index.php/$0 [PT,L]
```

config file

```
$config['base_url'] = 'http://ec2-xx-xxx-xx-xx.us-west-2.compute.amazonaws.com/';
```

Answer (score 13):

You can change your **.htaccess** like this

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule .* index.php/$0 [PT,L]
```

and change the value of "**AllowOverride None**" on **/etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf** (if you use AMI Linux)

into "**AllowOverride All**"

after that **restart** your apache with command like this:

```
sudo service httpd restart
```

It's work and tested on my aws ec2.

Comment: You just need to replace that string under this <Directory "/var/www/html">

Comment: Is anyone else struggling with this? I must have tried 20 different offered solutions at this point and none are working for me on ec2.

Comment: I have same issue, but this solution work's for me. Thanks

Answer (score 8):

```
(if you use ubuntu)
Activate the mod_rewrite module with

     sudo a2enmod rewrite

and restart the apache

     sudo service apache2 restart

To use mod_rewrite from within .htaccess files (which is a very common use case), edit the default VirtualHost with

     sudo nano /etc/apache2/sites-available/000-default.conf

Search for “DocumentRoot /var/www/html” and add the following lines directly below:

    <Directory "/var/www/html">
        AllowOverride All
    </Directory>

Save and exit the nano editor via CTRL-X, “y” and ENTER.

Restart the server again:

     sudo service apache2 restart
```

Comment: mine issue was to enable ` sudo a2enmod rewrite' thanks :)

Answer (score 3):

Justudin is correct!

Also you can use the "**AllowOverride All**" rule to only your project; writing in **/etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf** something like this:

```
<Directory "/var/www/your_website">
    AllowOverride All
</Directory>
```

Answer (score 1):

Only you can use the "AllowOverride All" rule to all deployed application; writing in /etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf :

```
 <Directory "/var/www/html">
     Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
     AllowOverride All 
     Order allow,deny
     Allow from all
 </Directory>
```