# EC2 Mod Rewrite changing AllowOverRide None to All

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

[How to edit httpd.conf file in AMAZON EC2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15112424/how-to-edit-httpd-conf-file-in-amazon-ec2) 
[codeigniter .htaccess in amazon ec2 removal of index.php not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17080302/codeigniter-htaccess-in-amazon-ec2-removal-of-index-php-not-working)

As i read at the above problems, i realized that my problem is the same with them. So, i should change my httpd.conf file in my Amazon EC2 instance to make my htaccess file work.

I connect to my instance via ssh client and it Linux terminal i execute the code below.

```
 sudo nano /etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf
```

Result of this code i see the page:

```
#
# This is the main Apache HTTP server configuration file.  It contains the
# configuration directives that give the server its instructions.
# See <URL:http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/> for detailed information.
# In particular, see
# <URL:http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/directives.html>
# for a discussion of each configuration directive.
#
# Do NOT simply read the instructions in here without understanding
# what they do.  They're here only as hints or reminders.  If you are unsure
# consult the online docs. You have been warned.
#
# Configuration and logfile names: If the filenames you specify for many
# of the server's control files begin with "/" (or "drive:/" for Win32), the
# server will use that explicit path.  If the filenames do *not* begin
# with "/", the value of ServerRoot is prepended -- so 'log/access_log'
# with ServerRoot set to '/www' will be interpreted by the
# server as '/www/log/access_log', where as '/log/access_log' will be
# interpreted as '/log/access_log'.

#
# ServerRoot: The top of the directory tree under which the server's
# configuration, error, and log files are kept.
```

So, i don't know what should i do after seeing this. Where i will change AllowOverRide None to AllowOverRide All, because i don't see anything like this.

And after changing AllowOverRide None to AllowOverRide All, should i restart the server with any command.

Answer (score 2):

You don't want to mess with the httpd.conf file for adding `AllowOverride`. You should do that in the vhost config of the virtual host that you want to enable htaccess files in.

Otherwise, if you can't modify the vhost config (or there simply isn't one), then just add this to `httpd.conf`:

```
<Directory />
    Options None
    AllowOverride All
    Order deny,allow
    Deny from all
</Directory>

<Directory /path/to/your/htdocs/>
    AllowOverride All
</Directory>
```

The `/path/to/your/htdocs/` is where your htaccess file or document root is.

Comment: Thanks for reply, but i'm totally zero at using linux terminal. After SSH connection, on terminal, how i will reach and change vhost config. If you know any good tutorial about this subject or explain how to do this step by step, i will be very thankful.

Comment: @YusufCanGürkan No idea where vhost config is stored on your EC2 instance, it's in different places depending on the distribution. You could try running: `find /etc/ -name '*.conf' | grep apache` to see if that brings anything up that looks like "vhost".

Comment: Finally, i made the changes you wrote and restart server but now my website does not open. It says 'You don't have permission to access / on this server'. What did i do wrong. I just change config file as you wrote upside.

Comment: @YusufCanGürkan try geting rid of the first `<Directory />` block

Comment: Thank you very much, finally it worked but should i worry about getting rid of <Directory /> block, can it be problem for security?

Comment: @YusufCanGürkan It's just one of those default things that are in vhost config by default

Comment: so, it will not make any problem even if it does not exist?

Comment: keep in mind that you need to restart your apache when you save changes: `service httpd restart`

Comment: @YusufCanGürkan where did u find vhost config?